# Getting a new nested resource's parent id for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a resource, Decision, that belongs_to Group. Group has_many decisions. I want a group's primary key (id) to be saved on integer field group_id on every decision that's saved in the database. I'm doing it this way and it works, but it seems like a really stilted way to do it. Is there a more direct or "Railsy" way to do it?

To start, my controller action/view has a group instance variable and I link to a form this way:

```
<%= link_to "New decision", new_group_decision_path(@group) %>
```

..so that my form is on /groups/:group_id/decisions/new

My new method under **DecisionsController** creates a new @decision for the form and passes it the :group_id I got from params.

```
def new
  @decision = Decision.new(group_id: params[:group_id]
end
```

I then pull that @decision.group_id in the form in **new.html.erb** and put it in a hidden_field so that the decision gets created with a group_id. Do I need to pass that group_id via params, then an instance variable, then via hidden field or is there a more direct way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, change your `new` action, to make it more "railsey"... Some slight changes to your controller

```
before_action :set_group, only: [:new, :create] # or other actions that do not apply here

def new
    @decision = @group.decisions.build # or new
end

def create
    @decision = @group.decisions.create(decision_params)
end


private
    def set_group
        @group=Group.find(params[:group_id])
    end

    def decision_params
        params.require(:decision).permit(:list,:of,:permitted,:params)
    end
```

So, you don't need to pass hidden fields or other means to clarify the group: It's already in the url...